# iOS Game Center Sign in Integration

Tags: ios, iphone, game-center

```
  GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController,    NSError *error) {}
```

I'm trying to implement that If the user is already currently logged in then Leaderboards button is available as soon as user opens the game app. However, if user is not signed in then the user must click on the custom GameCenterSignIn button to sign into GameCenter.

Having an issue with implementation because of above code. It won't let me do sign in twice in two different ways.

Why can't I use the above code twice in the same view controller. One in ViewDidLoad method and another in my custom GameCenterSignIn button to give the user a choice instead of force the user as soon as game starts with the GameCenter pop up or make the user leave the app in order to sign into GameCenter?

Answer (score 0):

You should register the authentication handler only once and earlier than in your view controller. From Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Users/Users.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH8-SW6):

> Your game should start to authenticate the player as early as possible
>   after launching, even before you present the user interface.

That's the starting point for implementing the rest of your scenario.